# Javascript self-executing function that gets global as argument

Tags: javascript, self-executing-function

I don't understand this function especially code after body. Please help.
This is full code. I understood body part.

```js
(function(global){
 
 //body part

})((this || 0).self || global);
```

Comment: Actually `this || 0` would return `0`

Comment: The code is used to pass the global object (`window` or `global`) to the function. The variable `global` is used to refer to the gloabl object within the function, whether the global object is `window` or `global`. The function is supposed to work in browsers and also in such environments (ex. webworkers), which have not `window` object.

Comment: Just for clarity, if this whole code is necessary? `(this || 0).self || global` shouldn't go like **`window || global` or `this || global`** ? Those are still ORs so expression like this `this || 0` doesn't look okay! .self looks little redundant.

Comment: @Goran.it Uh, you're right, I forgot the rest of the expression from my comment. `(0).self` would return `undefined`, ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start by breaking it down first we're making an anonymous function (function(){})

Then we're passing in a global variable this is a variable that is set so that it can be accessed within the scope of the application hower the anonymous function needs to have the global variable passed into the scope of the function so it knows to use whatever is passed to it through the global variable: (function(global){})

Then its telling itself to return the result of the function e.g the body part of the code back to the scope of the callback e.g the result of global parameter.

Hope this helps I'm terrible at wording my thoughts apologies if its of no help !

```js
(function(global){

  //body part
  
 })((this || 0).self || global);
```